# SFTP file upload very slow and stalls on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, file-upload, sftp

I am on a wired network and trying to upload some iso files through LAN.

The problem is that whenver I try to upload any files, the upload speed is very slow, as in the following screenshot:

[image]

Under the same exact conditions, but using Windows instead (even a VM under the same Linux), the upload is very fast, reaching about 15 MB/sec, as in the following screenshot:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Update: The following command fixes the slow upload and stalling:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_sack=0
```

To make it permanent, edit /etc/sysctl.conf and add this line

> net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 0

Then run:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```